# How to get dataItem from detail grid in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid. This grid contains hierarchy of detail grids.

Can I take dataItem for this detail grid when I click by row?

Comment: please provide the code you already have, it's hard to help with only that much information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following callback code.

function(e) {
    console.log($(e.target.closest('.k-grid')).data("kendoGrid").dataItem(e.target));
}

Answer (score 1):

```
   {
     title: "Click",
     width: "100px",
           command: [
                          {
                             name: "Click",
                             click: function (e) {
                             e.preventDefault();
                             var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        // You can access value of column by dataItem.columnID
                                                }
                          }
                     ]
   }
```

Here is a command name 'Click' in kendo grid. When you will click on command, appropriate function will execute.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
$("#main_grid_id").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr.k-detail-row").prev("tr"))
```